# XML - A number attached to namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces

Here's a WSDL:

```
 <types>
<!—Namespace declaration -->
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://KeithPij.org/WSLibrary/MyStore">

  <!—Element declaration for PlaceOrder request messages -->
  <s:element name="PlaceOrder">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="objOrder" type="s0:Order" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>

  <!—Type definition for the Order class -->
  <s:complexType name="Order">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OrderID" type="s:long" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ProductID" type="s:long" />
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ProductName" type="s:string" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Quantity" type="s:int" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="UnitPrice" type="s:decimal" />
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OrderDate" type="s:dateTime" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>

  <!—Element declaration for PlaceOrder response messages -->
  <s:element name="PlaceOrderResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PlaceOrderResult" type="s0:Confirm" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>

  <!—Type definition for the Confirm class -->
  <s:complexType name="Confirm">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OrderID" type="s:long" />
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Status" type="s:string" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>

  <!—Element declaration for CheckOrder request messages -->
  <s:element name="CheckOrder">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="nOrderID" type="s:int" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>

  <!—Element declaration for CheckOrder response messages-->
  <s:element name="CheckOrderResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CheckOrderResult" type="s0:Confirm" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>

</s:schema>
```

Could please someone explain what this means: type="s0:Order". I would understand it if it were written type="s:Order", it's a type declared in the namespace "s", but where does this "s0" come from?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be properly formed XML (there's an unmatched `<types>` tag at the beginning of the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make the wrong assumption. The type Order is not declared in the namespace 's'. From what I see here -

```
<s:schema>
....
    type="s:dateTime"
```

's' is the namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema. It is not possible that your custom-defined type Order to be part of this schema. Show the full WSDL and the declared namespaces on the toplevel (<wsdl> element)..

And s0: means that this is auto-generated identifier for the custom types defined in the schema.

Comment: Actually the wsdl is taken from MSDN website.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996434.aspx.

Comment: Then you had to download the complete example, and to look at the MyStoreSH.wsdl, and to find out that there is a declaration : xmlns:s0="http://KeithPij.org/WSLibrary/MyStoreSH". So this s0: comes from somewhere. But giving a partial wsdl, it is not clear where it comes from.

Comment: Thatnk you. I got confused by that Order type is also declared in the part I've given. If it's declared elsewhere, then why to declare it here again?

Comment: So namespace is a namespace... s1:Order is different than s2:Order. Probably the intention is to use the Order type defined in s0: instead of the current one, which as I recall should be however used without namespace - e.g. type="Order".